# ReferenceError: Window is not defined while importing htmlToDraft from html-to-draftjs on Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, draftjs

I wrote a separate function to convert html to draftjs, there I used `htmlToDraft` function from
`html-to-draftjs`.

`The Function`:

```
const htmlToDraftBlocks = (html) => {
    const blocksFromHTML = htmlToDraft(html);
    const state = ContentState.createFromBlockArray(
      blocksFromHTML.contentBlocks,
      blocksFromHTML.entityMap
    );
    const editorState = EditorState.createWithContent(state);
    return editorState;
  };
```

when running the server in node.js I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError : window is not defined
```

I have tried bellow way as well:

```
let htmlToDraft = null;
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  htmlToDraft = require('html-to-draftjs').default;
}
```

But in this case htmlToDraft remains null, not getting imported.

Why I am getting this error? Any help is appreciated

Comment: `window` exists only in the browser. if your app is running on the server, then there is no `window` object